Alternative proof that for $A \subseteq B$ we have $\sup A \leq \sup B$
I know the normal proof of this statement but I searched for a proof by contradiction. So here is my attempt.
Does this work?
Let $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$ be sets and $a\in A$ ,$b\in B$
If $A=B$ we have $\sup A = \sup B$ so we consider only $A \subset B$.
Assume that $\sup B < \sup A$ holds.
Then the following chain of Inequalities holds:
$b<\sup B < \sup A$ holds.
But then there exists $a \in A$ with $b<\sup B<a <\sup A$. But this contradicts $a \in A \subset B$.

This https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2106421/proving-that-if-a-subset-b-then-sup-a-leq-sup-b?rq=1 is already a proof done with the contradiciton. And your proof idea is on the right way, just the rigorousity and presentation is not good. Some gaps need to fill in on these kind of elementary proof.

@AngaeMT Sorry I haven't seen this one before. Could you highlight some gaps? Thank you for your help!

like for example, you do not need (and also didnt make the definition for) the existence of $b$. And also you want to claim there is $a\in A$ lies between $\sup B$ and $\sup A$ strictly, you can mention like you use the definition of supremum to clai,m that $\sup B$ cannot be an upper bound of $A$. Of courses you may think these are trivial, but writing a proof as a student on elementary topics shall be like this.

You can proceed as follows. Suppose that $A\subseteq B$ and $\sup(A) > \sup(B)$.
Thus there is some $a\in A$ such that $a > \sup(B)$, otherwise $\sup(A)$ wouldn't be the least upper bound.
In other words, this implies that $a > \sup(B) \geq a$, since $a\in B$, which leads to a contradiction.
Hopefully this helps!

I haven't downvoted you and agree with your answer
